# Get a list of 3 letter commands on Mac OS X

Tags: shell, wildcards, command

How can I either create or find a list of 3-letter unix commands on Mac OS X?

I'd like to create a new program/command for a project. I'd like to make it a 3-letter name, but I don't want to conflict with other unix commands. I am interested in seeing what is available before I settle on a particular name.

Comment: Pick your app name then Google "manpage <URNAME>" if theres a manpage for that combination change it.

Comment: I'm interested in seeing my options before picking a name though.

Comment: I would agree - picking a name that makes sense and then checking for and adjusting to work around conflicts seems like a better way to *not* confuse your user than just starting out with all of the TLA namespace not already taken.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
compgen -A function -abck | awk 'length($0) == 3'
```

(edit: its a bash builtin, so you should execute it in bash, and it will immediately give you the list of 3 char commands)

Comment: Chosen for its simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

Quick and dirty method, iterating over `PATH` and checking each directory.  Make sure your `$PATH` is something sensible before running.

```
save_IFS=$IFS
IFS=:
for dir in $PATH; do
        for file in "$dir"/???; do # ??? for 3 letter name
                if [ -x "$file" ]; then
                        printf %s\\n "$file"
                fi
        done
done
IFS=$save_IFS
```

Comment: `printf` is a little excessive for that task, innit? Why not `echo`?

Comment: Why not echo?  Just personal habit of never passing variable strings to `echo`, since `echo` is extremely non portable when passed arguments that look like options or contain backslashes.  In this case `echo` would probably be fine because on any reasonable system the first character of `$dir` would be `/`, although the path could still contain `\`, so `printf` is still better.  How is it excessive?  I hardly think the difference in efficiency matters for this task.  The few extra characters of typing save me the brain cycles of determining when passing variables directly to `echo` is safe.

Comment: This didn't seem to work for me. I tried to `echo $IFS` and got an empty string.

Comment: @KyleTolle New edit - fixed a bug where I had an unnecessary `$dir/` in front of `$file`.

Comment: @WarrenYoung: `printf` is more flexible, and much more consistent, than `echo`. I agree that `echo` would almost certainly work fine in this case. Both `echo` and `printf` are built-in commands, at least in bash.

Comment: I'd pipe the output through something like `sed 's,.*/,,' | sort -u` to remove the directory names and strip duplicates, and then perhaps through `fmt` so the output fits on my screen.